# How can I hide API keys on Squarespace?

Tags: javascript, api-key, squarespace

I am using a fetch within a code injection to get some events data to show on my Squarespace site.  The code for the fetch is working and returns a response which I am able to display.

The fetch looks like this

```
let response = fetch(
            "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=MYAPIKEY"
          )
            .then((response) => //...
```

What is the best practice for keeping MYAPIKEY safe and accessible within a Squarespace site?

My first guess is that I will have to create a new unlinked and password-protected page, create a new code injection there, then somehow link to that page during the API call - but I'm not sure if that is truly secure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you figure out a way that worked?

Comment: No - got a helpful answer on the squarespace forum to explain why though https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/164123-hide-an-api-key-in-file-on-a-disabled-page/#comment-374104

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this may be to install and use ***"dotenv"*** from npm packages. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv.

After you install this package you create a folder called ***".env"***.  You can type apikey in this folder. Like This:  `API_KEY = 12313123213ASDAD`; then you include the package in your project and you can use api key as ***"process.env"***.

So once you've done these things, you can now use apikey in this way:

```
let response = fetch(
            "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=process.env.API_KEY // Its your api key
          )
            .then((response) => //...
```

also for git, You must add *".env"* in ".gitignore".

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @CanUver.  I've seen documentation about hiding API keys with a .env before, but I'm not sure how to execute this within a Squarespace webpage code injection.  Where would the package install be saved to in a Squarespace site?

Comment: I guess a site creation tool like "Wix". is this true ? If so, can you access the site's source code ? I guess I missed that. I'm not very familiar with it , but if you can access the source code, you can intervene. Just like html css.